# Root of power $p$ from $1$ in the field of $p$-adic numbers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

How to prove that there is no root of power $p$ from $1$ other than $1$ for $p$ not equal to $2$?

Comment: There are several definitions for the $p$-adic numbers (by inverse limits, or by completions of $\mathbb{Q}$, etc) You should mention which one you're using.

Comment: But all these definitions are equivalent i.e. define the same field up to isomorphism.

Comment: Use $f(X)=X^p-1=(X-1)(X^{p-1}+\text{(you know)}+1)$ and write down what $f(X+1)$ looks like.

Comment: Sorry, I need more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof which seems to rely only on the fact that every element $x \in \Bbb Q_p$ has an absolute value $\vert x\vert_p \in p^\Bbb Z$ (or additive valuation $v_p(x) \in \Bbb Z$), and basic properties of ultrametrics. However, underlying are the same polynomial manipulations as in Lubin's answer.

Namely, assume $\zeta \in \Bbb Q_p$ with $\zeta^p =1$ but $\zeta \neq 1$. Call $x := \zeta -1$. Then

$$1 = (x+1)^p = x^p+px^{p-1}+\binom{p}{2}x^{p-2} +...+px+1$$
so
$$0= x^p+px^{p-1}+\binom{p}{2}x^{p-2} +...+px =x\cdot(x^{p-1}+px^{p-2}+\binom{p}{2}x^{p-3} +...+\binom{p}{p-2}x+p)$$
and since $x\neq 0$, the second factor is zero, meaning
$$x^{p-1}+px^{p-2}+\binom{p}{2}x^{p-3} +...+\binom{p}{p-2}x = -p$$

The right hand side has absolute value $p^{-1}$ (or: additive valuation $v_p(RHS) =1$). However, if $\vert x\vert_p \ge 1$ (i.e $v_p(x)\le 0$), the left hand side has absolute value $\ge 1$ (i.e. $v_p(LHS)\le 0$). If, on the other hand, $\vert x\vert_p \le p^{-1}$ (i.e. $v_p(x)\ge 1$), then the left hand side has absolute value $\le p^{-2}$ (i.e. $v_p(LHS)\ge 2$) because each term has such value (because the binomial coefficients are all divisible by $p$, and $p-1 \ge 2$ -- here we use that $p\neq 2$, otherwise indeed $x=-2 \in \Bbb Q \subset \Bbb Q_p$). Contradiction.

(Indeed, the correct absolute value of $x$ would be $p^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}$ (i.e. $v_p(x) =\frac{1}{p-1}$) but no elements of $\Bbb Q_p$ have such value.)

---

I think one can also prove by elementary means that for every sequence of integers (or rationals) $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_n^p \rightarrow 1$ ($p$-adically), necessarily $a_n \rightarrow 1$ ($p$-adically). I leave that to you. **Update**: The argument I had in mind for that is basically the one that makes up the answer by user reuns now.

Answer (score 5):

You need to know the Eisenstein criterion for irreducibility: if $R$ is a unique factorization domain (like $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z_p$), and if $f(X)\in R[X]$ is monic with all lower coefficients divisible by the prime element $p$, and if $p^2$ does not divide the constant term of $f$, then $f$ is irreducible in $R[X]$.

Now consider $g(X)=X^p-1=(X-1)(X^{p-1}+X^{p-2}+\cdots+X+1)$. You want to show that the second factor, call it $h$, is $\Bbb Z_p$-irreducible, and in particular has no roots in $\Bbb Z_p$. Note that the degree of $h$ is $p-1$, and its roots are all the $p$-th roots of unity other than $1$.

Look now at $G(X)=g(X+1)=X\bigl((X+1)^{p-1}+\cdots+(X+1)+1\bigr)$, in which the second factor, call it $H(X)$, clearly has constant term equal to $p$. Now look at this equation modulo $p$: as an equation with coefficients in $\Bbb Z/(p)$, the field with $p$ elements, it becomes $G(X)=(X+1)^p-1=X\cdot X^{p-1}$. This shows that as a $\Bbb Z/(p)$-polynomial, $H(X)=X^{p-1}$, in other words, $H$ is monic with all lower coefficients divisible by $p$. Thus $H$ is irreducible, by Eisenstein, and the corresponding $h$ is also irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still have a question.Firstly my question was about the field of p-adic numbers and you write about $\Bbb Z_p$ (I suppose you mean the ring of integers modulo p?). Secondly my question is an exercise from famous book by Borevich, Shafarevich  "Number Theory" after section 3 where only basic definitions and properties were proven. So I suppose that solution of this exercise should be based on these definition and properties. I did not find where p-adic numbers definition or properties are used in your text.

Comment: No, $\Bbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers, the completion of $\Bbb Z$ with respect to the same topology that makes $\Bbb Q_p$ out of $\Bbb Q$. You asked about whether those roots of $1$ were in $\Bbb Q_p$, but everything happens in the subring $\Bbb Z_p$. I didn’t use any particular properties of $\Bbb Z_p$ other than that $p$ is a prime there. I talked about $\Bbb Z_p$ because you asked about $\Bbb Q_p$.

Comment: eug100: There are many different ways to show this result. If you are looking for a proof that only uses certain definitions and properties, you should state these explicitly in your question. I think that is what @Yanko was getting at in his first comment to your post.

Comment: Torsten Schoeneberg: you are right, I should have more accurately formulated the question. Is it possible to give a proof based on  "by completions of $\mathbb{Q}$" (without Eisenstein criterion and the fact that $\Bbb Z_p$  is a unique factorization domain)  ?

Comment: Yes, probably you can give a proof without Eisenstein. But you will need Hensel’s Lemma, I think, to extend the $p$-adic valuation to the field of $p$-th roots of unity. If you don’t know Hensel,  you’re probably Strictly Out of Luck.

Answer (score 2):

$\quad$ Otherwise I think there is that elementary argument :

$p\ne 2$.

$\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$ has $(p-1)p^{k-1}$ elements.

$H_k= \{ c \in \mathbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times, c \equiv 1 \bmod p \}$ is a subgroup of order $p^{k-1}$.

$(1+p)^{p^{k-2}} \equiv 1+p^{k-1} \bmod p^k$ so $1+p \bmod p^k$ is of order $p^{k-1}$ and it is a generator of $H_k$ cyclic (note the special case $(1+2)^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1 +2.2^{k-2}+2^2 \frac{2^{k-2}(2^{k-2}-1)}{2}\equiv 1\bmod 2^k$)

The elements of $H_k$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$ whose order divides $ p$ are of the form $(1+p)^{e p^{k-2}}$.

If $\zeta^p = 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ then $\zeta \equiv (1+p)^{e_k p^{k-2}} \equiv 1+e_k p^{k-1}\bmod p^k$ so that $\zeta \equiv 1 \bmod p^{k-1}$ and $\zeta = 1 $.

Comment: I like the nick user1952009 more than reuns. Don't ask me why!