# Galois group of unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is cyclic

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

I have seen that there for every $f$ there exists a unique unramified extension to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $f$, and it is $\mathbb{Q}_p(\delta)$ where $\delta$ is a primitive $(p^f-1)$-root of unity. Looking at the polynomial
\begin{equation*}
p(x)=x^{p^f-1}-1 \in \mathbb{Q}_p[X]
\end{equation*}
we see that it is separable with the roots $\{1,\delta,\ldots,\delta^{p^f-2}\}$ and splitting field being $\mathbb{Q}_p(\delta)$ so $\mathbb{Q}_p(\delta)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a Galois extension of degree $f$ with basis $\{1,\delta,\ldots,\delta^{f-2}\}$. An automorphism $\sigma \in \mbox{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p(\delta)/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is determined by where it sends $\delta$ and since $p(\delta)=0$ we see that $\sigma$ takes $\delta$ to a new $(p^f-1)$-root of unity. This means that $\sigma(\delta) = \delta^i$ where $i=1,2\ldots,p^f-2$. One can therefore look at the group homomorphism
\begin{equation*}
\phi:\mbox{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p(\delta)/\mathbb{Q}_p) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/(p^f-1)\mathbb{Z})^\times
\end{equation*}
defined by $\phi(\sigma) = i$ where $\sigma(\delta)=\delta^i$. This homomorphism is injective so $\mbox{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p(\delta)/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/(p^f-1)\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Unfortunately, $(\mathbb{Z}/(p^f-1)\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is not cyclic so my proof doesn't really work. In most notes I have read they use other results to prove this but I am interested in a more straightforward approach, if there is one.

Comment: Please clarify this question by stating exactly what "other results" you want to exclude from a proof. E.g. if we can use that the extension has degree $f$, it is easy along the lines of Alex Youcis' answer. Standard would be Hensel's lemma and using that extensions of finite fields are cyclic. In any case, note that you'll need *some* structure theory of $\Bbb Q_p$, since the result is not true for almost any other field. And if we don't know it yet, even the case $f=1$ needs a non-trivial proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49282/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295679/96384.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $(p^k-1)$-th root of unity. Then, it is true that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified of degree $k$. That said, the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are $\zeta,\zeta^p,\ldots,\zeta^{p^{k-1}}$. Note then that for any $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ you have that $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^{p^d}$ for some unique $d\in \{0,\ldots,k-1\}$. We denote this Galois element by $\sigma_d$. Since this extension is Galois it's not hard to see that $d\mapsto \sigma_d$ is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}\to\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

Comment: This seems to be a nice proof but how can you know that the roots of the minimal polynomial are $\{\delta,\delta^p,\ldots,\delta^{p^{k-1}}\}$?

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg Using the fact that the other roots of the minimal polynomial are other roots of unity, the fact that the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}/\mathbb{F}_p$ are just pth powers of each other, the fact that prime-to-p roots of unity are distinct mod $p$.

Comment: I am not aware of the fact that the roots of the minimal polynomial are p-th powers of each other. Where can I find a proof of this?

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg The fact that mod $p$ this is true? This is the usual fact that the Frobenius generates the Galois group mod $p$, which is what is secretly happening here as well.

Comment: So here is what I understand so far: If $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a generator then $\alpha,\alpha^p,\ldots,\alpha^{p^{n-1}}$ are all roots of the minimal polynomial. 
Here is what I don't understand: How can you translate this to a statement for $\mathbb{Q}_p(\delta)/\mathbb{Q}_p$? Can you explain what you mean by "the fact the prime-to-p roots of unity are distinct mod p"?

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg Right. Then use the fact that since $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified of degree $p$ that $\zeta\mod p$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}/\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Here is how I understand it:
Let $\bar{p}(x) = x^{p^f-1}-1 \in \mathbb{Q}_p[X]$ and $p(x)$ be the corresponding polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. We have $\bar{p}(\delta) = p(\delta) = 0$ with minimal polynomial $\bar{g}(x)$ resp $g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is still minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ since it is irreducible since $\bar{g}(x)$ is. So $\mathbb{F}_p(\delta)$ has deg $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ so $\mathbb{F}_p(\delta) = \mathbb{F}_{p^f}$ and $\delta,\delta^p,\ldots,\delta^{p^{f-1}}$ all roots to $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

Comment: Since $\bar{g}(x)$ has exactly $f$ roots and every root also root to $g(x)$ it follows that $\delta,\delta^p,\ldots,\delta^{p^{f-1}}$ are all roots to $\bar{g}(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg That's essentially correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92748/discussion-between-andreas-dahlberg-and-alex-youcis).

Comment: Let $\omega=e^{2i \pi /(p^f-1)}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(p,\omega-\alpha)$ a prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ above $p$ then the desired unramified extension of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ can be realized as $R=\varprojlim\Bbb{Z}[\omega]/\mathfrak{p}^n$. From there we can show $R=\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta]$ where $\zeta$ is the image of $\omega$ in $R$, which is a $p$-adic primitive $p^f-1$ root of unity. Since $[R:\Bbb{Z}_p] = f$ the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $h(x)=\prod_{j=1}^f(x-\zeta^{e_j})$, looking at $h(x)\bmod p$ we obtain $e_j=p^j$. The whole thing doesn't seem trivial to me, do you have a simpler solution ?

Comment: @reuns Just show that $h(x)$ has $\mathbb{Q}_p$ coefficients by observing that the coefficients $c_i$ generate the trivial extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and since $\mathbb{Q}_p(c_i)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$ (and thus is unramified) this implies that $\mathbb{Q}_p(c_i)=\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Of course I looked at the coefficients of $h(x)$, their reduction are in $\Bbb{F}_p$, but it has nothing obvious they are in $\Bbb{Z}_p$. I could use Hensel lemma, for this I would need to say the minimal polynomial $\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ of those coefficients are separable modulo $p$, using that $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ is unramified at $p$.

Comment: @reuns If you know that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$ is unramified, which the OP claims to know, then the fact that $\mathbb{Q}_p(c_i)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$ implies that $\mathbb{Q}_p(c_i)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ but from what we have just said this extension has trivial residue field, so is just $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Of course we **don't know** that $\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$ is unramified, as it is quite the same as what the OP wants to show. That $R/\Bbb{Z}_p$ is unramified follows from going to the localization $ \Bbb{Z}[\omega]_\mathfrak{p}$ and replacing $\mathfrak{p}^n$ by $(\pi^n)$. More generally if $h(x)\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ has no double root $\bmod p$ then the splitting field of $h(x)\in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ is an unramified extension.

Comment: @reuns My dude, the first sentence says that he knows it's unramified. He's asking to show the Galois group is cyclic, no? The fact that it's unramified is clear from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta]/\mathbb{Z}_p$ has trivial sheaf of differentials since its a component of $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^{p^k-1}-1)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92767/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-reuns).

Comment: Ok for the differentials, embedding $\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta]$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^{p^k-1}-1)$ is quite the same idea as looking at $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$, the idea being that we need separable polynomials to apply Hensel lemma and show the coefs of $h$ are in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, no need for them to be the minimal polynomials of the coefs of $h$.

Comment: @reuns Did you see the above link?